# Parse error when using sgvizler

Tags: javascript, jquery, sparql, sgvizler

I am trying to make a table with SGvizler. However, when I try to create the table, I get the following error:

```
3.084s: loadGVizScript: loading packages: sgvizler.js:952 
3.087s: loadGVizScript: loading packages: table sgvizler.js:952 
4.742s: Error: A 'parsererror' occurred in Query.saveQueryResults() sgvizler.js:952 
5.049s: loadGVizScript: packages LOADED: sgvizler.js:952 
5.052s: loadGVizScript: packages LOADED: table
```

The code I use is the following:

```
  <script>
  var boatValue;
  $("#res").click(function() {
  var boat = document.getElementById('boat');
  if (boat.checked)
  {
  boatValue = boat.value;
  }
  else
  {
  boatValue = "speedboat";
  }
  console.log(boatValue)

  $("#query").click(function() 
  {var Q = new sgvizler.Query();
  Q.query(`SELECT ?boat WHERE { ?boat s:BoatorNoat s:`+boatValue+` .}`)                                              
  .endpointURL("http://localhost/query/")                                                 
  .endpointOutputFormat("json")                                                 
  .chartFunction("google.visualization.Table")
  .draw("myElementID");
</script>
```

I repeat the var boatValue a couple of times, so maybe there is a problem with the memory/usage of the browser, but unfortunately I am not familiar with that. Hopefully, someone can tell me how to fix this problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation I can find, your syntax looks incorrect here:

`` Q.query(`SELECT ?boat WHERE { ?boat s:BoatorNoat s:`+boatValue+` .}`) ``

I think you need to use double quotes like this:

`Q.query("SELECT ?boat WHERE { ?boat s:BoatorNoat s:" + boatValue + ".}")`

Added some code below that I think will help. Not sure what all the click handlers you have are since there's no HTML posted:

```js
$("#query").click(function() {
  var boat = document.getElementById('boat');
  if (boat.checked) {
    boatValue = boat.value;
  } else {
    boatValue = "speedboat";
  }

  var query = "SELECT ?boat WHERE { ?boat s:BoatorNoat s:" +
    boatValue + ".}";

  console.log(query);
  /*Plug into your code below*/
  /*var Q = new sgvizler.Query();
  Q.query(query)
    .endpointURL("http://localhost/query/")
    .endpointOutputFormat("json")
    .chartFunction("google.visualization.Table")
    .draw("myElementID");*/


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="boat" value="someOtherKindOfBoat">
<input type="button" id="query" value="See Query">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem. The word +boatValue+ is now in the query, and is not linked anymore to the variable boatValue.

Comment: Problem is that it works for me in the console, but not when I try to make a table from it with sgvizler.. Then still the error as mentioned above.

Comment: To be honest, the code you posted is riddled with syntax errors. For example, the first click handler never closed. Would probably need all the code to track down the exact cause.

Comment: Print out the query after the query string is built and check that.  Note that `boatValue` must be a legal local part to a prefix name, not any string of characters.

Answer (score 0):

The prefix "s:" is not defined. That's a parse error in SPARQL.

Comment: I defined it in my localhost (stardog) database and in the html file, so I think that is not the problem.

Comment: Also got this response: {message: "Multiple prefix declarations for prefix 's'", code: "MalformedQuery"}
code
:
"MalformedQuery"
message
:
"Multiple prefix declarations for prefix 's'"

Comment: Just fixed that problem by removing one prefix, but the main problem is still there.